# Sequences and little-o notation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits

Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space and $J\in\mathcal{C}^1(X, \mathbb{R})$ be a functional. Let $(u_n)_n\subset X$ be a Palais-Smale sequence at level $c\in\mathbb{R}$, i.e.
$$J(u_n)\to c\quad\mbox{ and }\quad J^{\prime}(u_n)\to 0.$$

My question is: it is correct to write that
$$J^{\prime}(u_n) u_n = o(\|u_n\|)?$$

If yes, could anyone please help me to understand why?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Representing $J^{\prime}(u_n) u_n =\varepsilon_n\cdot \|u_n\|$ where $\varepsilon_n=J^{\prime}(u_n) \frac{u_n}{\|u_n\|}$ when $\|u_n\| \gt 0$ and $\varepsilon_n = 0$ when $\|u_n\| = 0$ we have, that $\varepsilon_n \to 0$, using $J^{\prime}(u_n) \frac{u_n}{\|u_n\|} \to 0$.

So, we can write $J^{\prime}(u_n) u_n = o(\|u_n\|)$.

Comment: I am sorry, but why you can say that $J^{\prime}(u_n)\frac{u_n}{\|u_n\|}\to 0$? We only know that $J^{\prime}(u_n)\to 0$.

Comment: $J^{\prime}(u_n)\frac{u_n}{\|u_n\|}\to 0$ mean, that $\|J^{\prime}(u_n)\frac{u_n}{\|u_n\|}\|\to 0$, where you take out scalars from norm.